# Multiple webservers on one machine

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, mysql, webserver, opensuse

I am attempting to setup a Dell Poweredge R720 with a variable number of separate instances of apache/mysql. This is because we wish to be able to update some of our systems, without affecting others.

Currently, I am attempting to achieve this by installing OpenSUSE 13.1 on the physical server, then I am going to install two (At the moment, this is variable) Xen virtual machines (OpenSUSE 13.1) and install apache, mysql etc on each of them. I then plan to install Apache on the host machine, and use it to redirect certain URLs to each of the servers based on which sub part of the site they are accessing. Please note, all webserver instances need to be able to bind to port 443.

So here comes the questions - Does this method sounds feasible to you? and/or are there betters ways of achieving this, and if so how (Links also suffice)?

Restrictions:

- Only a single physical server
- Must use OpenSUSE 13.1 (I might be able to stretch that to Ubuntu)
- Must use port 443
- The MYSQL databases must remain separate
- The Apache servers sources must remain separate.

Thank you.

Comment: Everything is feasible given enough time, but the whole Xen/hypervisor thing looks like a big performance waste. You can have multiple instances of Apache/MySQL on a single machine (compile & install them manually in their own directory instead of using the package manager). If security/privilege separation is a concern you can use LXC containers to separate users without the overhead added by an hypervisor.

Comment: @AndréDaniel one quick question however, can the multiple instances of apache/mysql all still bind to the ports 443 and 3306 respectively?

Comment: No, you should have a "master" Apache installation that will act as a reverse proxy for all other instances (that will bind to other ports), unless your machine has multiple IP addresses or interfaces, in which case each instance can get its own interface with its own set of ports.

Comment: You will need virtual domains or some method of differentiating the flow of traffic to machine1 vs machine2. If VM1 gets, for example, 192.168.0.1 and VM2 get 192.168.0.2 then it will work.  However, the outside world will only see the external IP address.  Direct port forwarding will not work because apache1 and apache2 use the same ports and mysql has the same requirements.